Border radius dosen't line up with inline shadow as table cell
I was adding a drop shadow to an element, and for some reason, the box-shadow was acting like the border had a different radius. But when I removed display: table-cell it rendered perfectly fine.
I also noticed that the incorrect radius of the shadow was the same radius as the outer part of the border. Here's an image that explains it better:



#square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #636363;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: table-cell;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 4px #5f5f5f;
}
<div id="square"></div>




Why you need table-cell to start with? It's not meant to be used like that

Change the border for an outline and it works.

@TemaniAfif I'm trying to use a table that way I can line up the height of the square with the height of some text.

@Paulie_D Using outline isn't the best because I want to use a gradient border. A mehod of doing that is using a linear gradient set to border-box and then using a transparent border. background: linear-gradient(/*bgcolor*/) padding-box, linear gradient(/*border*/) border-box; border: 3px solid transparent. I'm not sure if you can do linear gradients for outlines but another way for making  borders is with drop shadows, although making gradients with drop shadows isn't as easy.
